# how to monitor a node with cacti -collect data with script (shell..) no SNMP MIB

Tags: python, shell, snmp, cacti

I would like to set up the Cacti supervision tool, but among the nodes I want to supervise that do not support SNMP.
Here I thought about programming scripts shell on the nodes themselves to extract the requested output, but here I am blocked! How sent this measurement and displayed on Cacti!

Do you know a way to do it? any URL guide ? Thanks for guiding me

Answer (score 0):

The [Cacti manual covers this topic](https://docs.cacti.net/manual:100:3a_advanced_topics.1_data_input_methods).

Note that the scripts run on the Cacti server. In order to execute scripts on your targets, you could create a server script which uses SSH to connect to the target (I'm assuming that if the targets have a shell environment, they're hopefully accessible via SSH). After connecting, the server-side script can execute client-side script(s) the script and relay the output back.

Additionally, there's whole directory of example scripts [bundled with the source code](https://github.com/Cacti/cacti/tree/develop/scripts). In particular, there's [an example shell script](https://github.com/Cacti/cacti/blob/develop/scripts/diskfree.sh) which demonstrates outputting using the multiple field format described in the manual.